# Example sentence, Passive construction and tenses

Tags: tense, passive-voice, past-vs-past-perfect

I am learning passive construction and I have a problem.

Problem:
A: Did anybody call an ambulance to the scene of the accident?
B: Yes. (but nobody / injure / so it / not / need)

My task is to make a sentence using the words in the brackets.

My try:
Yes. But nobody was injured so it is not needed.

Is that correct? I'm not sure about the Past Simple ... But nobody has been injured so it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is grammatically correct and an acceptable answer. The simple past tense (“was injured”) would definitely work here, because the injuries happened at the moment of the accident, which is now in the past. The present perfect progressive (“has been injured”) would only work if the accident were recent and the aftermath of the accident can be linked to the present, which is true here so both would work.